# How to detect when python program is closed by pressing the "X" button

Tags: python, windows, interrupt, except, atexit

I need a python program that can't be closed by the user no matter what, unless the program ends of course. I tried the following based on other posts here:

```
import os
try:
    x = input("hi")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    os.startfile("bezaros.py")
```

Basically this would reopen the program every time it's closed (starting over the program is not a problem in my case, but if it wasn't restarted it would be even better)

It works when it is closed by pressing CTRL+C but not when the "X" button is pressed. I also tried the atexit module, but the same thing happened, it only worked when it is closed by CTRL+C.

How can I make sure that whatever method is usesd to exit the program, a line of code will run?

I use Windows 10 and the program is supposed to be ran in a command prompt window.

Comment: Generally hitting the "X" on the window closes the shell that's running Python, which indirectly ends Python and whatever code it's processing.  Because of that it will be extremely difficult to intercept.

Comment: python.exe either inherits a console or allocates a new one. Whether it's inherited from a shell is irrelevant. When the console is closed, every process that's attached to it gets sent a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` and has 5 seconds to exit gracefully before getting terminated. The CRT maps this event to `SIGBREAK`, but the way Python handles signals at a low level by setting a flag and immediately returning makes this useless to us. The process just gets terminated. We need a handler set via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`. This handler can spawn a new process that's attached to a new console.